# What hardware (flash cartridge) is necessary for Nintendo DSi Homebrew?

Tags: nintendo-dsi

What hardware do I need to install Homebrew on Nintendo DSi?
To be more precise, what do I need to ask if I go to a IT shop?

Are they likely to have it in any IT shop?

Any gaming shop?

If not, what kind of shop?

Comment: Hello Olav, and welcome to the site. Your question is a Shopping reccomendation and is considered off-topic for the site as outlined in our [faq](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: @alexanderpas This doesn't really strike me as a shopping recommendation. More of a technical-support issue. Olav isn't asking what to buy, but rather, what is needed. At least, that's how I read it.

Comment: While I don't believe it's a shopping recomendation, it's not a great fit with this site, I recommend trying [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Its DEFINITELY NOT a shopping recommendation.

It also has more to do with game consoles than electronics. 
(I think its a  "Flash Cartridge", and i could ask exactly what that is and how to get it....But still it could be the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2):

"Flash Carts" is a generic term for a number of different devices that work in different ways.  Most of the more recently available cartridges for the "DS" series of handhelds work by storing data on a MicroSD card, and they fit in the "Slot 1" or "DS Card" slot on the DS.

It is highly unlikely that you will find one in a local shop, as they're gray market devices at best.  Certainly no major retailer stocks them anywhere I've ever been.  Once upon a time, it was said they were available in vending machines in Japan, but Nintendo has since sued and cracked down to remove them.

The other issue is counterfeiting - since these devices are gray market, the actual vendors for them are a bit shady. It can be hard, especially over the internet, to get a "real" one of these amidst the fakes.

Most of the time you're going to have to deal with some type of importer, usually out of Hong Kong, if you want to find one of these.  The market shifts pretty quickly, but one site that tends to be a good resource for this type of thing is [GBATemp](http://gbatemp.net/).  Check their forums for more information.

Be warned that Nintendo is very much against these devices, and they may take action against you for using one.